# What are the limitations of array size in elastic search?

Tags: elasticsearch

I have document which can have a tag array.

```
{
   "name" :"User 1",
   "friends":["user2","user3","user4"]
}
```

What are the performance implications of having several elements on friends Array on insertion , retrieval etc.

Also , when a new element is appended to an array of million elements in ES, how does it impact overall perf. Is the entire array replicated to replica shard or only delta ?

I could not find implications of array size in documentation.

Comment: Elasticsearch, or rather Lucene, doesn't really update a document. It's always an atomic remove&add. This page on the ES website explains it better: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/update-doc.html

Comment: I have been creating arrays with over 15,000 elements with no problem at all.

Comment: Is the entire document replicated to the replica or only the translog and and the same delete and create operation is executed on replica too. I am thinking about network here.